# Ignore local change when switching branch on both branch without stash/commit

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a git project with 2 branch `test` and `master` and a `start.sh` file.
The `start.sh` file on the remote repository is configured to run the project without specific option, but on my server I need some option (as the ip or the port) so I made a local version of the file, and every time I pull an update, I stash the file and then pop it after the local repository is update.

But now that I have the `test` branch, the problem is if I unstash  the file and then change branch, the change on the file is propagated to the other branch (git don't warn me about local changes as I saw on some post) and the `start.sh` file on `test` which is originally different from the one in `master` is now the same and the change can't be undone.

I'm now stashing `start.sh` every time I switch branch and pop the right stash in the list every time I need to relaunch my application, but it's a bit heavy, so I would like to know if there is a way to avoid this by:
- setting local change on different branch which are ignored by git when you pull

It's not a big problem, but I am curious if there is a work around or if I didn't understand something about git and how to use branch.

I also realised I have another problem. I have a `config.json` file with some secret token which is in the `.gitignore` and which isn't affected by the `git stash`... the token in the `test` branch and in the `master` branch should be different, but now, every time I modify the file in one branch, the change is also made in the other branch

Comment: Configure `branch.master.rebase` and don't bother stashing, just commit your local-only changes and never push them, when you `git pull` your work will be rebased onto the new tip.

Comment: Thanks, it's working as I want. I didn't think about that.